# Django cannot resolve the name of the db service

Tags: django, docker-compose

I have a django application dockerized and a postgresql server. I'm using docker compose to put both them together. The problem is that I always get this error:

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: "badger-dev"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        links:
            - db:db
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "badger-postgres"
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

I have also tried the following config with the same result:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        image: "badger-dev"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        links:
            - db:db
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
    db:
        image: "badger-postgres"
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
networks:
  djangonetwork:
      driver: bridge
```

These are my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 
          'NAME': 'dbhvu01u3e3fug',  
          'USER': 'postgres',                           
          'PASSWORD': 'postgres',                       
          'HOST': 'db',                           
          'PORT': '5432', # Use PgPool
     }
}
```

Any idea why it's not working? I have also tried adding depends_on, but with the same result too. I'm using pycharm, if that is of any help.

Comment: Container `links` are deprecated, did you try without? No need for `container_name` as well.

Comment: I have tried to delete links and container name and I'm getting the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: "badger-postgres"
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
    web:
        image: "badger-dev"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db:db
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
networks:
  djangonetwork:
      driver: bridge
```

Comment: This is exactly my example but with depends_on added? I said in my question that I already tried that and it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

At the end was that my db container was exiting after running the postgres start command. Adding something like `CMD service postgresql start && tail -f /dev/null` to the Dockerfile solved the problem.